# How to calculate the a delta function times derivative of a function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration, dirac-delta-distributions

It is clear to me that when we are talking about delta function, we should always understand it as a distribution, for example,:
\begin{equation}
\int \delta(x-x') f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(x')
\end{equation}

However, starting from here, I am confused by the following questions:

1. How do we calculate the integration of a derivative times delta function:
   \begin{equation}
   \int \delta(x-x') \frac{d f(x)}{dx } \, \mathrm{d} x 
   \end{equation}

Do we have
\begin{equation}
\int \delta(x-x') \frac{d f(x)}{dx } \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{df(x')}{dx'}
\end{equation}

2. How do we calculate the integration of a derivative times delta function with different arguments:
   \begin{equation}
   \int \delta(x-x') \frac{d f(x')}{dx } \, \mathrm{d} x 
   \end{equation}

Do we have
\begin{equation}
\int \delta(x-x') \frac{d f(x')}{dx } \, \mathrm{d} x = 0 \quad \text{for df(x')/dx=0}
\end{equation}

I was totally bemused by this variables and arguments.

Comment: What is $x'$.... is it some constant value of the variable $x$, like saying $x_0$....?

Comment: This question doesn't belong on the physics stackexchange, as it's purely a mathematics question.  Try posting on the math SE instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1)$ Consider $\frac{df}{dx}$ as a new function say $g(x)$. Then the answer using the distribution definition of delta function is simply $g(x')=\left.\frac{df}{dx}\right|_{x=x'}$.

$(2)$ Here, I think your notation $\frac{df(x')}{dx}$ means the function $g(x)$ from $(1)$ above evaluated at $x=x'$. As such it is a constant inside the integral, since the integral is over $x$ not $x'$. So it just comes out of the integral and you get
$$
\int \delta(x-x') \frac{d f(x')}{dx } \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{d f(x')}{dx }.
$$
So indeed
$$
\int \delta(x-x') \frac{d f(x')}{dx } \, \mathrm{d} x = 0 \quad \text{for} \quad \frac{df(x')}{dx}=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer you second case first; if you have $\delta(x-x') \frac{d f(x')}{d x} dx$ and imply that $\frac{d f(x')}{d x} =0$, the equation will also be null. However, in the case where $\frac{d f(x')}{d x} \neq 0$, you'd have a different result.

As for the first question, you're right, it will result in $\frac{d f(x')}{d x'}$ as $\delta(x-x')$ applies on everything. However, it would be easier to do/see, as tmwki wrote, if you substitute $\frac{d f(x)}{dx}$ with $g(x)$.

It is not my favorite note, but a quick research led me to this format of note which could be a good starting point.

https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/diracdeltafunction.aspx